# Take control from one tablespace and put into another in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, controls, position, tablecell

There's a table on a web form. The table has 4 rows with 3 columns in each. And several buttons are placed in these table columns. Let's say in design time Button btnSearch is in the 1st column of the 2nd row of the table. How can I change the buttons location to 3rd column of the 4 row?

Comment: Is there a postback in-between this move? Or do you just want to move it in the client?

Comment: No, there's no post back. It happens on the page_load event.I just need the client to see more neatly aligned buttons.

Comment: How is the grid constructed? Can't you just change it, I think we might need some more information about what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Here's link to the page:   http://i.imgur.com/6Q9Sa.png  Upon Page_Load if the user type is 3 then only Input and User buttons are visible.But as you might guess after that the layout will be like this: http://i.imgur.com/YLfoC.png. Button Top's are not aligned.I would like to control the layout of those buttons when I control their visibilities.That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be with jQuery. Like say:

```
$('#tableDataToMoveTo').append( $('#btnSearch') );
```

Where tableDataToMoveTo is the ID of the TD you want to move your button to.

You can download jquery, and read up on its usage, at jquery.com

Edit:

Seeing as how this is a question of showing specific users different buttons, why don't you just use an if statement and only make enough tablerows for the specific user? Like this:

```
<% if (roleID == 1) {%> (htmlcode for roleid 1 buttons) <%} 
else if (roleID == 2) { %> (htmlcode for roleid 2 buttons) <% } %>
```

I hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: do I put this code just in the C# code. Will c# recognize this query. When I write $ the compiler refuses to recognize it.And how do I get that "tableRowToMoveTo"? How do I tell it to move the button to a specific table column?

Comment: No, you don't. This is jQuery JavaScript. You need to download jQuery from www.jquery.com, and put it within <script type="text/javascript"> tags. #tableRowToMoveTo is the ID of the tabledata tag you want to move the button to.

Comment: Thank you very much Andreas. I appreciate your effort.

Comment: No problem, here's another idea though: Why don't you just don't use tables for the layout, instead using an unordered list with a set width, and place the buttons in listitems? That way, if there's only one button, it'll be on top. Hope this helped, and good luck!